# Copying to a variable

Tags: acumatica

Why is it necessary sometimes to copy an instance into a variable, update the variable and then update the instance with the variable ?

```
    protected virtual void INRegister_ToSiteID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row != null)
        {
            foreach (INTran item in this.transactions.Select())
            {
                INTran updated = (INTran)this.transactions.Cache.CreateCopy(item);                  
                updated.ToSiteID = ((INRegister)e.Row).ToSiteID;
                this.transactions.Cache.Update(updated);                    
            }
        }
        Set1Step((INRegister)e.Row);
    }
```

Why can't we update the property itself directly, e.g. item.ToSiteID ? Is it because it prevents firing an event or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **CreateCopy** method in order to update a DAC field was required before version 5.x. As of right now, there is absolutely no reason to create a copy of a DAC record unless you intentionally want to copy all field values from one DAC record to another.